# Empty AJAX response Chrome / Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery function which autofills an input field using the Google autocomplete API. Basically, an AJAX request is made to an PHP file which uses file_get_contents() to return JSON back to the application, and then upon success the results are displayed. Easy enough.

However, I seem to be having a problem displaying the results with both Chrome and Safari. The results is just blank, though behaves as if it has been successful in that it follows through with the callback function sans the JSON data. If I replace file_get_contents() with something simple, like printing "Hello", then the text come backs successfully.

I have tries adding a header to the offending PHP file, and I have tried adjusting the url from relative to absolute. Nothing seems to work, and it is starting to drive me crazy.

My ajax request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'},
  cache: false,
  url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax/locations.php',
  data: {data: input},
  async: false,
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(a){
   - do something with a -
  }
});
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: use dataType: 'json',

Comment: Could be a hundred of things. What is 'input'? What's in the PHP file? What "doesn't work"? What does the console say? And WHY on Earth do so many people use SYNCHRONOUS ajax???

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, no luck. Still blank.

Comment: +1 for "SYNCHRONOUS ajax??"
@mimewear, this is a GET request are you sure in your PHP file it is also a GET not POST ? mind sharing complete code ?

Comment: I tried synchronous just to see if it would fix anything. But the PHP file is simply this: echo file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json... etc, etc"). I am not getting any errors in the console, etc - the callback function just seems to act as if everything is fine. Both IE & Firefox display the correct results, so the script does function properly.

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting in php? Quite often error reporting is turned off so you will just get a blank page/response in case some error occurs.

Comment: Yeah, no PHP errors. Everything is fine from that side of things. It couldn't be a more simple file, so any error would be easily spotted & remedied.

Comment: I get a 404 on the URL you provided. Try adding an `error()` function and see what it outputs? (And please remove that `async:false`. It can only harm.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's caused by Chrome/Safari enforcing XHTML standards that IE/Firefox don't. This post has more details and a helper function for cleaning up responses so they work in Chrome/Safari: http://randomdrake.com/2009/03/30/php-solution-for-ajaxxhtml-entities-problem-with-chrome-and-safari/

Comment: Hello, sorry I have been busy the last couple of days, but I think you might be moving in the right direction. I decided to try pasting the json from Google directly into my PHP file (i.e. echo "json string"), and this comes back correctly - and the application proceeds as intended. So something is happening with the encoding. If I paste the same json into another file and use file_get_contents("pasted.json") I get the same blank/empty response.